# Submitting html code without setting ValidateRequest to false

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a textbox and i want the user to be able to submit a youtube embed code.
Is this possible without setting 'ValidateRequest' to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html encode the text and put it in a hidden input before submit,
and then decode it on the server after submit.

Answer (score 2):

No, you must turn it **False** to allow users to enter youtube embed code. you just have to encode your code to prevent cross site scripting.

Comment: So , when we  encode the code and save them in db, how can we show them to the user just like the html ? Isn't dangerous to decode them ?

Comment: @Mostafa just show directly, as it is in encoded form in db so no need to decode.

Comment: Thanks for responding . I have a freeTextBox control on form , Users submit some html text and i use AntiXss.HtmlEncode() method to encode them , But when i retrieve them from database and represent them in form , it's not like html ( no formats ) . for instance like this : simple text <b>bold text</b> <u>underline </u><br>

Comment: @Mostafa Use AntiXss.GetSafeHtmlFragment(), as it only remove that tags that are not whitelisted.