# html code submitting to code-behind not working with ValidateRequest = true in <% @page >

Tags: asp.net

By default ValidateRequest = true inside <% @page >. Because of that I'm having problem while submitting HTML code from client side to server side. If I make ValidateRequest = false than it works. But I don't want to disable server side validation. Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submitting html code without setting ValidateRequest to false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961855/submitting-html-code-without-setting-validaterequest-to-false)

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behavior of the ValidateRequest directive.  It is meant to prevent basic CSS attacks.

- http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1sw53ds.aspx

You could HTML encode the input before you pass it to the server, which I believe would get around this.  This is what you would want to do for security reasons anyway.